# Reading a PNG file and retaining the correct format in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm trying to read a PNG file and then send the data out as a response to an HTTP request.

When I rename the original PNG file to a `.txt` and open it in an editor, I see the contents are something like this

```
8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452
0000 074c 0000 0632 0806 0000 00bc 541d
2300 0000 0467 414d 4100 00b1 8e7c fb51
9300 0000 2063 4852 4d00 0087 0f00 008c
0f00 00fd 5200 0081 4000 007d 7900 00e9
```

However, when I try to manually read it and store it as a String in Java, I get a result like this:

```
ï¿½PNG

���
IHDR��L��2���ï¿½T#���gAMA��ï¿½ï¿½|ï¿½Qï¿½��� cHRM��ï¿½��ï¿½��ï¿½R��ï¿½@��}y��ï¿½��<ï¿½��ï¿½s<ï¿½w��
/iCCPICC Profile��HÇï¿½wTTï¿½ï¿½Ï½wzï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½zï¿½.0ï¿½ï¿½. Qfï¿½�ï¿½Mlï¿½ï¿½@DEï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½b!(ï¿½`HPb0ï¿½ï
```

As a result, I get an error in browsers saying the image is malformed.

Seeing as the output contains a couple readable things like "PNG", I believe I'm changing the encoding when I read it. But, I have no idea how to make it retain the "correct" format / encoding. Here are two different approaches I've tried, both of which result in similarly broken results.

```
        InputStream inputStream = NewWebserverLauncher.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(url);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            // todo: error
            return "NO INPUT STREAM. Looked for \"" + url + "\"";
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return result.toString();
```

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

Would appreciate pointers on how I can read the PNG correctly!

Comment: Don’t make a String of the bytes, just save them ”as is”.

Comment: Unfortunately the library I'm using only accepts `String` when setting the response body. Basically I read the `InputStream` and then have to call `context.result(String)` to set the response body. I'm sure it can be worked around, but at this point I'm mostly curious if I can store the data correctly as a String

Comment: Is it a public library? If so which? I don’t think you will be able to pass your image as a String (without some serious hacks)

Comment: My mistake, I just took a closer look and saw that the library (Javalin) does have a way to set an `InputStream` as the response instead of just a `String`. I'll adjust my code so that it can use `InputStream` when necessary. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, when I try to manually read it and store it as a String in Java

You shouldn't do that. It's just not text.

> Would appreciate pointers on how I can read the PNG correctly!

Don't try to store *binary* data as if it's *text* data.

Your code that copies the data into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is broadly correct - until the last line, when you convert it into a string. Just don't do that. Call `toByteArray()` instead.

The text you've shown at the start of your post is the *hex* representation of the bytes. You didn't say what you opened it in, but I suspect it's some program that is either dedicated to editing binary files, or something that recognizes that you're opening a file which really isn't text, despite the file extension.

You've written a comment indicating that the library you're using only allows you to send a string as a response. If that's really the case, use a different library. Any library which *really* assumes that every HTTP response is text is fundamentally broken, and you may well find there are many other problems with it. I would look carefully first though - you may well find there *are* ways of sending binary data, and you just haven't found them yet. You may want to post a new question that's specifically about "How can I send a binary response using library X?" rather than about how to treat binary data as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I took a closer look at the docs and found that the response can also take an `InputStream`, my mistake! I'm using one method to handle both text and binary data, and for text data I need to edit the data before sending the response, which is why I was using the String version. I'll make the necessary changes so that I can use `InputStream` when necessary.